# Защита от спам-роботов

Tags: защита

Подскажите алгоритмы защиты от спам-роботов, помимо капчи, которая на текущий год уже не является защитой (взламывается).

Comment: правильно настроенный фаервол, премодерирование.

Но самый надежный способ от спам ботов - выключить сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Генератор вопросов. Например исторических фактов. Но лучше вопросы по тематике сайтов.
Например на сайте электротехники было бы уместно разместить фотографии резисторов, а в ответ должны правильно написать сопротивление. Ну и т.д.